# How do I troubleshoot an error trying to add a Farm Administrator

Tags: error, central-administration, roles

Can someone please explain to me HOW to figure out what is causing the unbelievably vague error of "Server Error in '/' Application....turn off custom errors...blah, blah, blah"

Of course, I have changed ever web.config in the c:\InetPub\wwwroot folder (and subfolders) to have the correct setting....and still.

When I attempt to add a new user via the 
'Central Administration:Site Settings:People and Groups - Farm Administrators'

I'm able to enter the user name on the 'Grant Permissions' but when I click ok...I get the error.

any advice would be great!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course, I have changed ever web.config in the c:\InetPub\wwwroot folder (and subfolders)

Actually, starting from SharePoint 2010, they have several additional web.config files in 14 hive. If error is happening under _layouts folder, you will need this web.config:

**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config**

Also, you can find this error details either in your LOGS folder, or using PowerShell [Get-SPLogEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607589.aspx). Sometimes, Windows Event Viewer can also help you.

Comment: This is not something specific for sp2010. It is because layouts is a virtual application in IIS and hence has its own web.config. This was also the case in sp2007 :)

Comment: Please refer from "hi <user>.." and "hope is helps" in comments. We want to keep the answers as precise and clear as possible :) for more info on this issue read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: fixed, thanks for the link, didn't know that it's a bad practice :(

Comment: no problem, keep the good answers and questions coming :)

Comment: Changing that web.config does indeed give me a more useful error.  Not that I have a clue why it's upset since I AM a member of the Local Administrators group.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a windows server 2012 environment?

Try running psconfig a couple of times....